# SurfaceView displayed incorrectly in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, surfaceview

The red area is my scan view.
Sometimes When I go this Scan view from another view.
It has displayed incorrectly like the pictures_B.
It happened very low rate.
I checked that the width and height of the surfaceView, surfaceHolder, and canvas are correct.
So I don't know what happened.
Sorry I can't provide code to test because it takes a lot of space
I would like to ask if anyone is having the same problem or having some suggestion for me.
Thanks!

pictures_A (normal) and pictures_B (error):

[image]
[image]

I try to print picture_B width and height of the surfaceView, surfaceHolder, and canvas are same as normal type(picture_A)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.